# Using cross-sectional data for OLS/logit models (Stata)

Tags: database, dataframe, stata

I have a cross-sectional dataset with the data example below, where the variable (id) refers to each individual in the df and rows represent the different number of Reddit posts written by each username, which vary across individuals.
My goal is to use OLS regression to predict average sentiment, based on individual-level covariates which are all measured at the username-level. For instance, the indicator "collective_action_prop" counts the proportion of mentions across all posts for a given username.

Currently, I ran the OLS model as follows:

```
regress avg_sentiment avg_response economic_demand_prop
```

However, I am not sure if I am correctly running the OLS regression at the username-level with the current data structure where each row represents a Reddit post but the variable id refers to usernames:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float id double float double()
 1                 -1         1                  0                 1
 2                 -1         0                  0                 1
 3                  0         0                  0                 0
 4                  0         .                  0                 0
 4                  0         .                  0                 0
 5                  1         6                  0                 0
----
```

Comment: This isn't a Stata programming problem; it is about whether your statistical analysis is well conceived, which depends on your research goals.

Comment: Note, that nowhere in my post did I mention that it was a STATA "programming problem" However, given that my data are stored in Stata, I thought it makes sense to tag Stata, which people do if their data are stored in R/Python etc..

Comment: Questions about using statistics with Stata are in my view off-topic here. It's not a matter of whether a Stata tag makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your average sentiment is bounded between (0,1) then OLS would not be right since it assumes that the outcome variable is continuous (-Inf,Inf). You need to re-conceptualize your problem via transformation of the outcome variable or a beta regression

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify: the average sentiment variable indeed ranges from -1 being most negative to 1 being most positive, however, the usernames shown in the example above happen to have values that are >= 0.
Based on this, would it still make sense to use an OLS model?

Comment: I've never applied regression with an assumption that the outcome can be any real value! In any case the OP's question makes clear that the outcome can be negative, as does their comment.

Comment: @nesta1992, no it does not make sense to use OLS in this scenario. OLS assumes your outcome is real valued and your values are bounded [-1,1]. You would get predicted values outside the range of [-1,1]. You need to either transform your outcome or work with models that have different distributional assumptions.

Comment: @dhc The previous comment is confused, OLS does **not** assume that the outcome is bounded, which is indeed why you might (not would) get predicted outcomes outside their allowed range. In practice with this kind of data that is unlikely. The issue echoes disagreement in econometrics and elsewhere about the merits of linear probability models.  "does not make sense" is too strong given that competent and experienced researchers disagree.

Comment: Answer should be edited if only because the statement that the OP's outcome lies in (0, 1) is wrong.

Comment: Correct Professor @NickCox of Durham University, the DV variable ranges from -1 being most negative to 1 being most positive, with a median of -.25 and an average of -.10.

Comment: To say that OLS does not assume outcome/error terms is a real, is a fundamental misunderstanding of statistics and gauss-markov theorem. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem. To say that one might use OLS despite its important assumptions is rather poor advice--use models with distributional assumptions that match the data generating model. Otherwise, what stops anyone from using linear regression with binary data (and so on)

Comment: See Sir David Cox [not a relation] on the linear probability model as less than crazy https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.190067 Theorems are fine, but data analysis can use many different tools